# using jQuery to get absolute or relative position position of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'll try to explain what i'm trying to get. I've a div with position:fixed (at the bottom of a page) into that div, there is some other divs. What i want is to show another div (with absolute position) aligned to the right with those divs... in other words, i wan't to know the left position of the divs...

Comment: Do you mean the actual left position, or the CSS left position?

Answer (score 20):

Relative to the document:

```
$('#ID').offset().left
```

Relative to its offset parent:

```
$('#ID').position().left
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#ID').position().left
```