# Get the absolute position of a div relative to the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371379/using-jquery-to-get-absolute-or-relative-position-position-of-a-div) is quite similar to what I want I'm looking for, but my situation is different enough, I think, to merit a new question.

I have several divs positioned absolutely inside of a parent div (`position: relative`). I want to get the position of the children divs relative to the window. The jquery `offset()` method doesn't seem to work, because it gives me the offset from the parent div. Is there a way to get the absolute position of a div that has absolute position inside of a relative position div?

Sample html:

```
<div id="parent" style="position:relative;">
  <div id="child1" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left 8px;">Child 1</div>
  <div id="child2" style="position:absolute; top:20px; left 8px;">Child 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It might help untangle things if you could post some sample HTML that illustrates the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the `.position()` function too, however (though they're perpetually confusing to me) my understanding is backwards from what you've written: `.offset()` is relative to the document origin, while `.position()` is relative to the "offset parent".

I think it's the fact that the term "offset parent" contains the word "offset" that confuses me.

Comment: You have it right. `.position()` is relative to the parent and `.offset()` is relative to the document. But, since my divs are inside a relative position div, `.offset` is giving me the position relative to the parent, as is `.position()`.

Comment: Hmm ... that seems kind-of weird.  As I said, it might help to see a (possibly simplified) HTML sample to show the wrong answer you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at `.offsetParent()`, you can traverse up to the window and get the total offset.

See also http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=620402

Comment: I was hoping to find a simpler way to find the position in the window. I have decided instead to redesign the page so that I don't have to get the position. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with the html below.  The value I get for offset is different than position.    Is something else going on that changes where the parent div is positioned?  If another element is getting added to the DOM after you check the position and offset values, then maybe you need to check position later. Maybe using inline style as opposed to using CSS classes makes a difference?  (you will need to get json2.js from http://www.json.org/js.htm)

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" 
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var position = {};
        position.grandpa = { position: $("div.grandpa").position(), 
                             offset: $("div.grandpa").offset() };
        position.dad = { position: $("div.dad").position(), 
                         offset: $("div.dad").offset() };
        position.me = { position: $("div.me").position(), 
                        offset: $("div.me").offset() };
        alert(JSON.stringify(position));
    });
</script>

 <style type="text/css">
    div.grandpa {
        position: relative;
        border: 3px solid blue;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: White;
    }
    div.dad {
        position: absolute;
        top: 4px;
        left: 4px;
        border: 2px solid green;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    div.me {
        border: 1px solid red;
        padding: 10px;
    }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grandpa">
        John
        <div class="dad">
            Joseph
            <div class="me">Justin</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Hi
Use the position () function of jQuery library.

Create a Div called Stage and another called Content.
On Stage Div write position absolute, top and left. In Div Content type position absolute, top and left too.

Ok?