# jQuery : how to find the coordinates of center of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the coordinates of center of a divand position another element based on the center of this div. The div is actually movable on the screen ?
Any ideas?

Comment: Use `.offset()` to get the top and left coordinates, then add 50% of the `.width()` and `.height()` to it.

Comment: [Get the position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371379/using-jquery-to-get-absolute-or-relative-position-position-of-a-div) of the div and its dimensions and do some math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set margin to auto as this will center(left and right only) the div within its parent. as a bonus, if you want to center it from the top/bottom then just retrive the height of the parent, divide by 2 and use that as your value for top padding. example: http://jsfiddle.net/VsqdW/2/