# How to relatively position a div within a div?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to position a div within a div in the right left corner like:

[image]

and I'd like to position a div within a div in the center like:

[image]

How might this be done in the easiest way? :O

Comment: why is this being marked down??

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @foreyez it's being downvoted because this Q can be answered with a modicum of googling.

Comment: baloney, i've googled this and there were many different ways to go about it so it got me mixed up. i've put in nice pictures and got many answers. there is good information here.

Comment: @JamesHill upvote for the nice link dude...or a thumbs up d(^_^o)

Answer (score 2):

**Top/Right inner element:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZAKAz/1/

```
.outer { height:200px; width:200px; position:relative; }

.inner { position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:50px; height:50px }
```

**Centralized inner element:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZAKAz/

```
.outer { height:200px; width:200px; position:relative; }

.inner { position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;
         margin: -25px 0 0 -25px; width:50px; height:50px }
```

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside top_right">
    </div>        
</div>
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside center">
    </div>
</div>​
```

css:

```
.outside {position:relative;width:200px;height:200px;border:2px solid black}
.inside {position:absolute;width:50px;height:50px;border:2px solid blue}

.top_right {top:0;right:0;}

.center {top:50%;left:50%;margin:-25px 0 0 -25px}
```

the container has a `position:relative` to make that display where it's intended on the page, and allow the `position:absolute` to work as expected within the boundaries of the container.

the center css there is putting the div at 50% from the `top` & `left`, then using negative `margins` of half the `width`/`height` of the `div` to pull it into the center.

I think top right is pretty much self-explanatory.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/BK7qr/

Answer (score 0):

Use Div box

for the main div

position: absolute

the rest of divs inside use:

position: relative

check http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/ hit#4

Answer (score 0):

you could try my previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726717/1146022

example: http://jsfiddle.net/VsqdW/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

#div2 {
    width: 100;
    height: 100;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the top left corner use this:

```
.ContainingDiv {position: relative;}
.InsideDiv {position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;}
```

For the center, do the next:

```
.InsideDivCenter {margin: 0px auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

try float proprety :

```
.divA
{
float:right;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Answer (score 0):

your first question is as simple as: div.foo { float: right; }

or you could just valign=center... however the above answers are more thorough this is just the way that i would try first...at least for the one you want in the center of the div.

NOTE: valign as been deprecated in favor of using the css attribute vertical-align. so you will have to do it with vertical-align. sorry, i forgot that. i am a little old school from the days of table lay outs :)